# get TransactionReceipt Not found

Tags: go-ethereum, etherscan

I am coming across a problem where. I ask for the transaction Receipt but get not found in return. what I am trying to do is establish the created contract address, and obtain the receipt to see the contract address.
For example:
In Geth when I throw this command at it. I get null.

```
eth.getTransactionReceipt("0x9ecc9482e5ce1616b6a71ea6b7434d53418836c53a1176b27873c7f7190fc599")
null
```

on etherscan you can see clearly there is a contract address and other information.
Is there a proven method to retrieve receipts, or do these receipts disappear over time. if that's the case. what method is used to discover contract addresses?

Comment: Are you connected to the right network?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You first need the actual Transaction from the transaction hash you have, then you can get your receipt. I often use WaitMined() (import "github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/accounts/abi/bind", which awaits the transaction to get mined.

so first `tx, isPending, err := eth.TransactionByHash(context.Background(), txHash)` and then `receipt, err := bind.WaitMined(context.Background(), dialedClient, tx)`.